# unexpected execution of Exceptions in python

Tags: python-2.7, exception

I am novice to python and i came up with this problem. i have made a simple program for calculator. In add function, i have used try- except. when this line is encountered (if decide== 'no' or decide== 'n':), it displays the print line "return(" You have exited ")" but it also throws the exception. I cant understand why.

```
import sys

def menu():

    print "calculator using functions"
    print "Choose your option:"
    print " "
    print "1) Addition"
    print "2) Subtraction"
    print "3) Multiplication"
    print "4) Division"
    print "5) Quit calculator.py"
    print " "
    return input ("Choose your option: ")


def add(a,b):
    try:
        print a, "+", b, "=", a + b
        print " Do you want to continue: "
        decide=raw_input("yes or no: ")
        if decide== 'no' or decide== 'n':
            return(" You have exited ")
            sys.exit(0)
        elif decide=='yes' or decide== 'y':
            menu()
        untrusted.execute()

    except:
        print "wrong choice!!!"
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print "Error: %s" % e
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: You're not showing the code that raises the exception.  `add` immediately stops executing after you `return` from it, whatever is calling `add` is the thing raising the exception.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Now if i choose 'No' for if decide== 'no' or decide== 'n', it is running my menu() {which should happen when i choose 'yes'}...  if decide== 'no' or decide== 'n': is not working

Comment: your program is wrong please write good program.

Comment: If you type `No` as the answer, then `if decide == 'no' or decide == 'n'` is not true, which is why it is running your menu method. It is working as expected, because `No` is not the same thing as `no`.

Comment: I am typing no, then also it is excuting: Do you want to continue: 
yes or no: n
 You have exited 
wrong choice!!!

Comment: @user3201916 There is not an issue of whether you select yes/no is the program but there is mistake in the way you are calling `add` method and the way you are returning form it...check that....and refer the code from my answer.

Comment: @user3201916 If you got your answer then accept it or else update us with whatever problem that still persists.

Comment: thanx y.dixit... your method worked!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ....I suppose `return(" You have exited ")` is problem here and istead of `sys.exit(0)` try `return 0` I dont know why its a problem but it works. I tried it for both yes and no conditions.

```
import sys



def menu():

print "calculator using functions"
print "Choose your option:"
print " "
print "1) Addition"
print "2) Subtraction"
print "3) Multiplication"
print "4) Division"
print "5) Quit calculator.py"
print " "
return input ("Choose your option: ")


def add(a,b):
try:
    print a, "+", b, "=", a + b
    print " Do you want to continue: "
    decide=raw_input("yes or no: ")
    if decide== 'no' or decide== 'n':
        return "n"
        #sys.exit(0)
    elif decide=='yes' or decide== 'y':
        return "y"
    untrusted.execute()

except:
    print "wrong choice!!!"
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print "Error: %s" % e
    sys.exit(0)

while(True):
selected_option=menu()
if(selected_option == 1):
    print "Enter first number:"
    no1 = raw_input()
    print "Enter second number:"
    no2 = raw_input()
    option=add(no1,no2)
    if(option == 'y'):
        print "yes selected"
        continue
    if(option=='n'):
        print "no selected"
        sys.exit(0)
```

output:
Do you want to continue:

yes or no: re

wrong choice!!!

### Error: `<type 'exceptions.NameError'>`

---

Do you want to continue:

yes or no: y

yes selected

calculator using functions

Choose your option:

1) Addition
2) Subtraction
3) Multiplication
4) Division
5) Quit calculator.py

### Choose your option:

---

Do you want to continue:

yes or no: n

no selected

root@yogesh-System-model:~#